# Withdraw money from amount value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 2 columns, name and amount. I want to write a statement where I am subtracting 100 from the amount of the person with the name 'Joe'

I am confused on whether this would be using the SELECT or DELETE statements. All of the delete examples I have seen involve deleting an entire row or column, i just want to subtract from a  value

Comment: If you want to change the values in columns in a row, then you would use `UPDATE`.

Comment: Alternatively you may use [DELETE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DELETE.html) and [INSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html) with the new amount.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, if you want to just retrieve the data then use this (without case)

```
SELECT name, amount-10 
from [table_name] 
where name='Joe'
```

Or if you want to permanently update table with the manipulation

```
UPDATE [table_name] 
set amount=amount-10 
where name='Joe'
```